# Gsub replace the last space of an unknown length of the last string

Tags: r, regex, substring, gsub

I have this data which contains tv series data

```
"!Next?" (1994)                     1994-1995
"#1 Single" (2006)                  2006-????
"#1 Single" (2006) {Cats and Dogs (#1.4)}       2006
"#1 Single" (2006) {Finishing a Chapter (#1.5)}     2006
"#1 Single" (2006) {Is the Grass Greener? (#1.1)}   2006
"1941" (2009) {(#1.9)}                  ????
"1942" (2011)                       2011-????
```

I need to divide this into series name| production date|episode name| year of release

The episode name is uneven(it might or might not be present) as can be seen above for the case of 1942(last record).Hence I would be counting characters from the last character.

Currently, I have done `name| production date|` but for to add a `pipe(|)` before the year of release is a bit tedious.

I want an output like this

```
"!Next?" |1994|                     |1994-1995
"#1 Single" |2006|                  |2006-????
"#1 Single" |2006| {Cats and Dogs (#1.4)}       |2006
"#1 Single" |2006| {Finishing a Chapter (#1.5)}     |2006
"#1 Single" |2006| {Is the Grass Greener? (#1.1)}   |2006
"1941" |2009| {(#1.9)}                  |????
"1942" |2011|                       |2011-????
```

I have got the first 2 pipes using sub but not able to get the 3rd one.
please if anyone could help

Comment: Based on the data you shared here, you could simply gsub the  `}`  with a `} |` and it should place a pipe after the episode name...and if there is no episode name, the on on the production date will serve as a divider between it and the air date.

Comment: @bethanyP but the thing is all records dont have a `}` in the data...thats the problem...hence I thought of doing it from the last character...for example the last record.. If u could help me create a regex with the help of the last character,for ex using `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use backreference for this kind of tasks (`input` is the vector of strings to be modified):

```
gsub(pattern = "([0-9?-]+$)",
     replacement = "|\\1",
     x = input)
```

Basically it searches for the maximum string located at the end that consists from digits, "?" and "-"; takes that string and replaces with its modified copy by preceding "|".